# Autumn Revolutions bittersweet not fruiting

Tags: vines, berries

Two years ago, I planted the Autumn Revolutions cultivar of bittersweet near a garden trellis. The vines took over the trellis quite nicely, but it has not fruited.

I know most varieties of bittersweet require both a male and female plant to produce fruit, but this cultivar is supposed to have both male and female parts on the same plant, and thus be self-fertile.

I did try to plant two separate vines on either side of the trellis, but only one thrived.  I have not seen any flowers on the established plant either year.

I am about to re-plant the second vine, but was wondering if I there is anything else I can do to encourage fruit production on the established plant.

Perhaps the plant I purchased was faulty and did not actually have both the male and female parts?

Answer (score 3):

The [grower's site](http://www.firsteditionsplants.com/autumn-revolution-bittersweet) indicates

> The majority of the flowers formed on Autumn Revolution are perfect,
>   meaning that the flower itself has both male and female parts.

So you do not need two plants.  It can sometimes take a few years for a plant to get established and able to flower and fruit.